# Finding a character in a string through recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

So, I'm super newbie to programming and I need to implement a method which finding a char in a string EXACTLY through recursion and return index of this char, but if this char isnt exist it returns -1. And I dont understand how I can do this returning. I need to that incrementing is not carried out. I may not add 1 when I call the recursion, but how then can I return the index of the found element without creating "int index". Can u focus me in a right thoughts? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCTRJ.png)

P.S. As I understand it, I step out of the recursion step by step, adding 1 each time, but how do I exit immediately with a value of -1?

Comment: Call the method recursively, check if the result is -1, then you also return -1, otherwise you add 1 to the result you got and return that.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Try running your code in "Debug Mode" and add breakpoints at several places. And then trace your code to check whats happening. Will definitely help

Comment: I did it. My problem is after "return -1" returns to the place "1 + method call" and until the stack is empty (as I understand it) it is executed and instead of -1 I get 50

Comment: "P.S. As I understand it, I step out of the recursion step by step, adding 1 each time, but how do I exit immediately with a value of -1?" If you really want to get creative, you can throw an exception, it will still go through the call stack, but it will work. Take this as a fun idea and not as something to actually be done on an actual project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of solving this, you most likely want the first index of the occurrence.

You can use a `startAt` that gives the current position and increment as you go along.

```
int FindIndex(string value, char item, int startAt = 0)
    => startAt >= value.length
        ? -1
        : value[startAt] == item
        ? startAt
        : FindIndex(value, item, startAt + 1);
```

You can overload this method and provide a public method that takes just the `value` and `item` parameters without any `startAt` parameter and forward the call to the one that does. Since this is tagged as C#, you will need to declare these methods inside a class meaning that one of them can be `public` while the other one can be `private`.

```
int FindIndex(string value, char item)
    => FindIndex(value, item, 0);

int FindIndex(string value, char item, int startAt)
    => startAt >= value.length
        ? -1
        : value[startAt] == item
        ? startAt
        : FindIndex(value, item, startAt + 1);
```

You can check from the end of the string.

```
int FindIndex(string value, char item)
    => value.Length == 0
    ? -1
    : value[value.Length - 1] == item
    ? value.Length - 1
    : FindIndex(value.Substring(0, value.Length - 1), item);
```

A more straightforward approach is to cover for the `-1` when you didn't find anything. Either by multiple recursive calls.

```
int FindIndex(string value, char item)
    => value.Length == 0
    ? -1
    : value[value.Length - 1] == item
    ? value.Length - 1
    : FindIndex(value.Substring(1), item) == -1
    ? -1
    : 1 + FindIndex(value.Substring(1), item);
```

Or just by storing the result instead of doing the call two times.

```
int FindIndex(string value, char item)
{
    if (value.Length == 0)
        return -1;
    else if (value[0] == item)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        var result = FindIndex(value.Substring(1), item);
        if (result == -1)
            return -1;
        else
            return result + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't "exit immediately" from the recursion.
And you shouldn't return "1 + method call".
Instead, call the method, get the result into an integer variable, and check the result.
If the result is -1, return -1.
Otherwise, return 1 + result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
public int FindChar(char c, string s, index = 0)
{
  if(index >= s.Length)
  {
     return -1;
  }
  if(s[index] == c)
  {
    return index;
  }

  return FindChar(c, s, index + 1);
  
}
```